# How did rishi Bhringi take birth with 3 legs?

Tags: scripture, rishi

There are many sculptures of rishi Bhringi in temples of South India; which show he has 3 legs. Is there any scriptural basis that he had 3 legs by birth or did he get them after birth?

Here are some pictures of sculptures:

[image: rishi bhringi worshiping shiva parvati]

[image: rishi bhringi]

Comment: Maybe it is a reference to when he kicked Viṣṇu (unclear which form)?

Comment: @Aupakarana He was Rishi bhrigu who kicked Vishnu and not rishi Bhringi.

Comment: Well, according to Wikipedia: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhringi (This is tantra, so I doubt we could find a better source) Bhṛṅgi got his third leg from his correction by Pārvatī. I guess it also reference the three forms he took during the story, a Bhṛṅga, a rat/bee thing that is hard to identify, and a Nivātakavaca/their animal equivalent.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa Please compile an answer.

Comment: I think someone else did a more detailed version already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *[Pratima-Kosha: Encyclopaedia of Indian Iconography, Vol. 4](https://archive.org/details/pratimakosaencyclopediaofindianiconographyramachandraraos.k.vol4col_202003_57/page/n213/mode/2up)*, S. K. Ramachandra Rao explains the symbolism and backstory behind Bhṛṅgī's three-legged and  skeletal appearance in temple art:

> BHṚṄGĪ
>
> An important attendant of Śiva, who is distinguished by his total
> devotion to Śiva. **A story found in [Kālikā-purāṇa (ch. 45)](https://archive.org/details/kalikapuranawithenglishtranslationintroductionindexmissingunknown_202003_601_v/page/n645/mode/2up) makes him
> (along with Mahākāla) born out of the semen of Śiva**, which was
> received by the fire-god Agni. He was entrusted with the
> administration of Śiva's troops; and Bhṛṅgī and Mahākāla were made the
> door-keepers.
>
> Better known accounts relate that he was a great sage who was given to
> the exclusive worship of Śiva. Pārvatī, who did not receive any
> attention from him, grew jealous and complained to Śiva. Śiva,
> thereupon, assumed the form of Ardha-nārī, incorporating Pārvatī into
> his own body, so that the sage would worship Pārvatī  also when he
> worshipped Śiva. But when the sage who arrived to do circumambulation
> found Śiva and Pārvatī united, he immediately became a beetle (bhṛṅga)
> and bore a hole in the middle of Ardha-nārī's body so that he could go
> round Śiva's half only. This is how he came to be known as Bhṛṅgī.
>
> **Pārvatī, who became indignant at Bhṛṅgī's device, cursed him to become
> emaciated and weak. The two legs of the sage could no longer support
> the body, whereupon Śiva provided him with a third leg.**
>
> Bhṛṅgī is usually shown in the parivāra of Śiva, with Nandī, Taṇḍu,
> Tuṃburu and others. He is represented as a lean figure with frail
> limbs, sage-like in appearance, with matted hair done up as a tall
> crown, and dancing in devotion. He is distinguished by having three
> legs. He is said to have a monkey's face, owing to Pārvatī's curse,
> and he is sometimes classed as a bhairava.

The [Skanda Purāṇa](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc365984.html) narrates a different story on how Bhṛṅgī ends up being cursed by Pārvatī but it doesn't say anything about Śiva blessing him with a third leg:

> #### Chapter 34 - Śiva Loses to Pārvatī in a Game of Dice
>
> **Bhṛṅgī said**:
>
> 97. **You must not talk too much, O beautiful lady. My master is invincible and devoid of aberrations**, O lady of good waistline.
> 98. You possess only womanly temperament, O lady of excellent face. You do not know the Lord who is greater than the greatest. Formerly, O
>     Bhavānī, you had come to Ugra, the great lord, after keeping Kāma in
>     front of you.
> 99. Has this ever been remembered by you? (Do you recollect) what has been performed by the Pināka-bearing Lord formerly? O beautiful lady,
>     tell us (if it is so). Indeed Kāma was made Anaṅga (bodiless) by him.
>     The park belonging to that Mountain, your father, had been burned.
> 100. It was after that, that Śiva, the Supreme Soul, the lord, greater than the greatest, was propitiated by you.
> 101. **On being told thus by Bhṛṅgī, she became excessively angry.** Even as Maheśa was listening, the infuriated lady spoke these words to
>      Bhṛṅgī:
>
> ...
>
> **Girijā said**:
>
> 112. O Bhṛṅgī, be quiet and steady. Otherwise go away. You do not know what should be said and what should not be said. Why do you babble
>      like a ghost?
> 113. By which man or woman was Śiva brought here by means of penance? Who am I? Who is this as understood by you? You speak to me with the
>      attitude of difference.
>
> 114-115. Who are you? By whom have you been united? Wherefore do you
> talk too much? **I will curse you. What will Śiva do now?**
>
> On being spoken to reproachfully by Bhṛṅgī, the chaste lady then
> cursed: "**O stupid Bhṛṅgī, O favourite one of Śaṅkara, be devoid of
> flesh.**"
>
> 116-117. After saying thus, Pārvatī, the goddess, beloved of Śaṅkara,
> became furious. She held Śaṅkara by the hand. The lady of slender
> limbs took away the serpent Vāsuki from his neck.
>
> ...

Comment: Wait, does it say Ṛṣi when it says the sage, or is he literally the same as the Nivātakavaca Bhṛṅgī/Bhṛṅgin, known formally as Andhaka.